# Support, measure, function

Tags: measure-theory

I have a question about a support.

Let $m$ be Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^{d}$ and $f$ be a continuous function on $\mathbb{R}^{d}$. We define $\mu(A):=\int_{A}|f|dm,\,A{\rm \,: Lebesgue\,measurable\,set }$.

I want to prove ${\rm supp}[\mu]=\overline{\{f \neq 0\}}$.

Here
\begin{equation}
{\rm supp}[\mu]=\mathbb{R}^{d} \backslash \cup_{A\in \mathcal{S}}A,\,\mathcal{S}=\{ A \subset \mathbb{R}^{d}: A {\rm \,is \,open},\,\mu(A)=0 \}
\end{equation}

I can prove $\overline{\{f \neq 0\}}\subset{\rm supp}[\mu]$.

Proof:
Since $f$ is conti, $\mu(A)=0,\,A \in \mathcal{S}$ implies $f=0$ on $A$. i.e. $\{f\neq0\}\subset A^{C}$. Therefore $\{f \neq0\} \subset \cap_{A \in \mathcal{S}}A^{C}={\rm supp}[\mu]$. Since ${\rm supp}[\mu]$ is closed subset of $\mathbb{R}^{d}$, $\overline{\{f\neq0\}} \subset {\rm supp}[\mu]$.

I have a difficult time with  ${\rm supp}[\mu] \subset \overline{\{f \neq 0\}}$. How do I get this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply note that $A := ({\rm supp}f)^c$ is an open set with $f \equiv 0$ on $A$, so that $\mu(A) =0$.

Hence, $A \in S$, which yields ${\rm supp}\mu \subset A^c = {\rm supp}f$.